# How to switch to typedef from template aliasing?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-aliases

I have a template class that basically implements registry design pattern.
Values are registered with Keys and are stored in some container:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, 
    template <typename...> class Container >
class registry
{
public:
    typedef Key   key_type;
    typedef Value value_type;


    typedef std::pair<key_type, value_type> element_type;
    typedef Container<element_type> container_type;
```

Then, I can use it with sequence containers like this:

```
registry<const char*,void*, std::list> r1;
registry<const char*,void*, std::vector> r2;
```

I can even use it with alias:

```
template <typename T>
using alias_container = std::array<T, 10>;

registry<const char*,void*, alias_container > r4;
```

But I can't figure out how to use it with typedef like this:

```
template <typename T>
class my_container2 
{
    typedef std::array<T,3> type;
};
```

I basically want something like this:

```
registry<const char*,void*, my_container2::type > r5;
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. A typedef is not a template.

Answer (score 2):

`type` is dependent on the template type provided to `my_container2`.  In order to use it you need to specify the template parameter like

```
registry<const char*,void*, my_container2<some_type>::type > r4;
                                          ^^^^^^^^^ template type here
```

This is the same concept as iterators to standard types.  You can't use `container_type::iterator`.  You have to use `container_type<some_type>::iterator`.

Comment: Nathan, thank you for your answer. In my case <some type> will be deducted by registry template: it should be std::pair<const char*,void*>, but I would prefer to refrain from explicetely specifying it.

Comment: @YakovGerlovin - You cannot do what you want. There is no such thing as an template typedef. The authors of C++ investigated doing just that and found lots of issues. They instead added the concept of aliased templates, which use `using alias_name = some_type_possibly_templated;`.